# Better way of assigning Value into model property Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I am working on asp.net mvc, I had seen 2 ways for binding model properties, the ways are below

> Model

```
Public class TestModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int name { get; set; }
}
```

> First Way

```
TestModel model = new TestModel();
model.id = 1;
model.name = "user";
```

> Second Way

```
TestModel model = new TestModel() { id = 1, name = "" };
```

I think so second way is much faster compare to the first one, what is better way to assign value into model property as per you guys?

Comment: first check [https://sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTAbgIYBO6AtgPbACmAGzjoAvOgB2/AO7oAKvwDOAF0p8hdANzIAkDt4DhAOgCWwMejjakeg0LhGJrLvwsAiAK6L+7N9aYsHNzqgjAWUrIKKmqGdPjoZhZwADSSzq7ibm7oAL7+AURQcACc1HbGTi60+QVFpeUwjunVjEQ5regdaJhhUaohugRITDrdJhLKCeZ46ADm/Mqa6N6LuR2jpHAADGku8fOrK0vtNic5QA===) ... and then it will be obvious that this question is *primarily opinion-based* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both solution have two step
1) defining a new instance by default value
2) giving new values to the properties

you can use an constructor to initialize default value in definition

```
Public class TestModel
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public int name { get; set; }
     public TestModel(int _id,int _name)
     {
          id=_id;
          name=_name;
     }
}
```